# Can I use the Kubernetes terraform provider on an azure kubernetes cluster?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform

Is it possible to create a namespace in an azure kubernetes cluster like below? I've not been able to get this to work as the kubernetes provider tries to create the namespace locally.

Is there a way to get the two providers to work together?

```
# AKS Cluster
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = var.aks_cluster_name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "${var.aks_cluster_name}-dns"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = var.aks_node_count
    vm_size    = var.aks_node_size
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

# Ingress Controller
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "ingress_namespace" {
  metadata {
    name = var.ingress_controller_namespace
  }
}
```

Have tried configuring the provider block to no success

Comment: Thanks for this but i'm getting the following error now kubernetes_namespace.ingress_namespace: Creating... ╷ │ Error: Post "test-dns-g2afd6vn.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443/api/v1/…": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority │ │ with kubernetes_namespace.ingress_namespace, │ on main.tf line 46, in resource "kubernetes_namespace" "ingress_namespace": │ 46: resource "kubernetes_namespace" "ingress_namespace

Comment: Please check your provider "Kubernetes" and how you passed the parameters inside it & also check Use kubectl directly from the command line to test access to the AKS cluster. If Kubectl also fails, it indicates a more general issue with your AKS setup or network configuration. This is the issue causing your blocker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to use the Kubernetes terraform provider on an azure kubernetes cluster and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The creation of a `Kubernetes namespace` in an `Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster` using Terraform, it's important to properly configure both the Azure provider and the Kubernetes provider in your Terraform configuration. The issue you're facing seems to be due to incorrect or incomplete configuration of these providers, causing Terraform to attempt to create the `namespace` in a local `Kubernetes cluster` instead of the `AKS cluster`.

**My demo terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.host
  client_certificate     = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.client_certificate)
  client_key             = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.client_key)
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks.kube_config.0.cluster_ca_certificate)
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "vkAKSCluster"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  dns_prefix          = "myakscluster"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_DS2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "ingress_namespace" {
  metadata {
    name = "ingressvk-namespace"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]